# IIS multiple sites on same ip with different ssl

Tags: windows, ssl, iis

I cant seem to run multiple sites using the same IP with different ports and different ssl cert.

site a is fine but site b is returning SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN because it's returning site a's ssl cert.

This is the error I get when trying to use it on the same ports hence I use different ports for the domains

[image]

Comment: What IIS version do you use? IIS 8 and above supports SNI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

1. First of all SSL certificates are most commonly issued against domain names instead of IP addresses.
2. In your scenario you have one IP address so only one certificate can be issued against one IP address.

Options:

1. Get multiple SSL certificates for your website domains assuming your websites will be hosted on different domains e.g. example1.com, example2.com
2. Get wild card ssl certificate and then use it for your multiple websites assuming your websites will be hosted on sub-domains e.g. site1.example.com, site2.example.com

[image]

Comment: Without mentioning SNI, this answer is incomplete.

Comment: I have an ssl cert for every domain and changed the ports per domain as well, but I still get the error.

Comment: What do you mean by changed domains per port? If you have different domains for each website why you need different ports for same IP address? In IIS you can you bind a domain to website with IP address set as "All Unassigned". I have attached a screenshot with answer

Comment: I added a screenshot to the initial post, so if you add the ssl to the same port on different domains you get that error

Answer (score 0):

So the solution provided by Moshin Mehmood did resolve the issue.

Any site on IIS will have to use SNI and there is no reason to supply a specific IP if all the sites use the same one, IIS will give an error about not having any default ssl bindings but that is a legacy thing and not cause for concern.

Thank you very much Mohsin.